# How are these strange UTF characters jammed together in twitter comment?

Tags: utf-8

Check this twitter https://twitter.com/transgendall/status/1286866479455940608

How are these characters ė̶̜͚̦̲̠̭̺̱̯̮̊̈́̾͜e̶͑̔̍̓̃̽ be typed?

If I click delete key they disappear partially like this ė̶̜͚̦̲e̶͑̔, seems like multiple strange characters are packed at the same position, how is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Arabic there are no vowels per se (in writing). The word sugar is written as سكر using three letters. To make the vowels "u" and "a" explicit, little signs are added on top of the letters: سُكَر
The added signs are typed normally as any other letter and appear automatically on top of the letter that got previously typed.

Trivia: The words sugar and alcohol are of Arabic origin along others  such as admiral, arsenal and magazine.

Comment: Very interesting! I like the way how they're vividly rendered.

Comment: You've seen nothing. Lookup Arabic Calligraphy. If you want I can get your name written like that :-)